# Short Circuiting Truth Test of Predicate Collection

Tags: clojure

Say there is the need to check if an argument passes one truth test of a given predicate collection.

codewise:

```
(fn [x]
  (or (pred1 x) (pred2 x) (pred3 x) (pred4 x)))
```

due to the implementation of `or`, this short circuits after the first truthy value. As intended.

How can this be rewritten by using a collection of predicates:

[pred1 pred2 pred3 pred4]

A funky way would be:

```
(fn [x preds]
  (some?                                 ;; nil->false  
    (some true? (map #(% x) preds))))
```

It also turns out that this one does not short circuit. Might be due to Clojure's chunking of lazy sequences.

Can we do this better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

clojure has a `some-fn` function for that:

```
user> ((some-fn true? false? nil?) true)
true
user> ((some-fn  false? nil?) true)
false
```

or for your case:

```
user> (defn any-pred? [x preds]
        ((apply some-fn preds) x))
```

another classic way is to do it recursively:

```
user> (defn any-pred? [x preds]
        (when-let [[pred & preds] (seq preds)]
          (or (pred x) (any-pred? x preds))))

user> (any-pred? true [false?])
nil
user> (any-pred? true [true?])
true
user> (any-pred? true [false? true?])
true
user> (any-pred? true [false? nil?])
nil
user> (any-pred? true [false? nil? true?])
true
```

Comment: Better `recur` than use explicit recursion.

Answer (score 0):

When I need short circuit, I use reduce with reduced.

```
(defn any-valid? [w & pred-fn-coll]
  (reduce (fn [v pf]
        (if (pf w)
          (reduced true)
          v)) false pred-fn-coll))

 (any-valid? 1 even? odd?)
 ;=> true
 (any-valid? 1 even? even?)
 ;=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's `map` that's doing the chunking in your solution.

Try

```
(defn any-true? [preds]
  (fn [x]
    (loop [preds preds]
      (and (seq preds)
           (or ((first preds) x)
               (recur (rest preds)))))))

((any-true? [odd? even?]) 3)    ;true

((any-true? []) 3)              ;nil

((any-true? [even?]) 3)         ;nil

((any-true? [odd? #(/ % 0)]) 3) ;true
```

The last example shows that the evaluation is lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

```
(defn somep? [x [p & ps :as preds]]
  (if-not (empty? preds)
    (or (p x) (somep? x ps))))
```

or

```
(defn somep? [x [p & ps :as preds]]
  (if-not (empty? preds)
    (let [res (p x)]
      (if-not res
        (recur x ps)
        res))))
```

Comment: Your first alternative could be `(defn somep? [x [p & ps :as preds]] (when (seq preds) (or (p x) (recur x ps))))`.